# Creating a QR code scanner using Augmented Reality

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I am using AR.js and AFrame to create an AR app. In this, I have to create a QR code scanner which will display the information encoded in QR code.

I have browsed for this but all I have found is how to encode barcode 3x3 into a QR code and then use it for Augmenting models. But I want to create a QR code scanner.

Can you guide me towards some resources or help me see how to implement it?

Comment: didn't try this, but check out https://medium.com/chialab-open-source/how-to-deliver-ar-on-the-web-only-with-a-qr-code-e24b7b61f8cb written by ar.js lead maintainer Nicolò Carpignoli

Comment: Well I have seen it and this isn't what I am trying to do. I need to create a QR code scanner.